# How to restart an Application in JavaFX with Preloader?

Tags: java, javafx, preloader

I know it is possible to call LaunchImpl but it needs an args array, so outside of the main it is useless for Reststart, but if I use just init() and start() of Application class the Preloader class isn't working anymore.

Using `init()` and `start()` but Preloader isn't restarting, of course.

```java
primaryStage.close();
Platform.runLater(() -> {
    try {
        final JavaFXApplication javaFXApplication = new    JavaFXApplication();
        javaFXApplication.init();
        javaFXApplication.start(new Stage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
});
```

Comment: Why don't you just store the args (if you have some) somewhere and then reuse them for the relaunch?

Answer (score 0):

You need to notify your `Preloader` after instantiating the application by calling `Application#notifyPreloader`. In your case this would look like:

```
javaFXApplication.notifyPreloader(new Preloader.ProgressNotification(0));
```

This works of course with other `Preloader.PreloarderNotification` instances.